# Constants of motion vs. integrals of motion vs. first integrals

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, integrals-of-motion, integrable-systems

Since the equation of mechanics are of second order in time, we know that for $N$ degrees of freedom we have to specify $2N$ initial conditions. One of them is the initial time $t_0$ and the rest of them, $2N-1$ are initial positions and velocity. Any function of these initial condition is a constant of motion, by definition. Also, there should be exactly $2N-1$ algebraically independent constants of motion.

On the other hand, Noether's procedure gives us integrals of motion as a result of variational symmetries of the action. These integrals of motion are also conserved but they are not always $2N-1$ in number. In consequence, we classify the system by their integrability.

So, what is the difference between the [constant of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion) and [integral of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion#Integral_of_motion)? Why do non-[integrable systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) have less integrals of motion when they should always have $2N-1$ constants of motion?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8626/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44576/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Why is one of the the $2N$ initial conditions the initial time? Shouldn't it be $N$ positions + $N$ velocities?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1) A [*constant of motion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion)
$f(z,t)$ is a (globally defined, smooth) function $f:M\times [t_i,t_f] \to
\mathbb{R}$ of the dynamical variables $z\in M$ and time $t\in[t_i,t_f]$,
such that the map $$[t_i,t_f]~\ni ~t~~\mapsto~~f(\gamma(t),t)~\in~ \mathbb{R}$$
doesn't depend on time for every solution curve $z=\gamma(t)$ to the [equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) of the system.

An [*integral of motion/first integral*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion#Integral_of_motion)
is a constant of motion $f(z)$ that doesn't depend explicitly on time.

2) In the following let us for simplicity restrict to the case where the system is a finite-dimensional autonomous$^1$ Hamiltonian system with Hamiltonian $H:M \to \mathbb{R}$ on a $2N$-dimensional symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$.

Such system is called [*(Liouville/completely) integrable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability) if
there exist $N$ functionally independent$^2$, Poisson-commuting, **globally** defined functions $I_1, \ldots, I_N: M\to \mathbb{R}$, so that the Hamiltonian $H$ is a function of $I_1, \ldots, I_N$, only.

Such integrable system is called *maximally* [*superintegrable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintegrable_Hamiltonian_system) if
there additionally exist $N-1$ **globally** defined integrals of motion $I_{N+1}, \ldots, I_{2N-1}: M\to \mathbb{R}$, so that the combined set $(I_{1}, \ldots, I_{2N-1})$ is functionally independent.

It follows from [Caratheodory-Jacobi-Lie theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Lie_theorem) that every finite-dimensional autonomous Hamiltonian system on a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ is **locally** maximally superintegrable in sufficiently small **local** neighborhoods around any point of $M$ (apart from [critical points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29) of the Hamiltonian).

The main point is that (**global**) integrability is rare, while **local** integrability is generic.

--

$^1$ An [*autonomous*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28mathematics%29) Hamiltonian system means that neither the Hamiltonian $H$ nor the symplectic two-form $\omega$ depend explicitly on time $t$.

$^2$ Outside differential geometry $N$ functions $I_1, \ldots, I_N$ are called **functionally independent** if $$\forall F:~~ \left[z\mapsto  F(I_1(z), \ldots, I_N(z)) \text{ is the zero-function} \right]~~\Rightarrow~~  F \text{ is the zero-function}.$$
However within differential geometry, which is the conventional framework for dynamical systems, $N$ functions $I_1, \ldots, I_N$ are called **functionally independent** if $\mathrm{d}I_1\wedge \ldots\wedge \mathrm{d}I_N\neq 0$ is nowhere vanishing. Equivalently, the rectangular matrix $$\left(\frac{\partial I_k}{\partial z^K}\right)_{1\leq k\leq N, 1\leq K\leq 2N}$$ has maximal rank in all points $z$. If only $\mathrm{d}I_1\wedge \ldots\wedge \mathrm{d}I_N\neq 0$ holds [a.e.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere), then one should strictly speaking strip the symplectic manifold $M$ of these singular orbits.

Comment: Here we implicitly assume that the Hamiltonian $H$ itself is functionally independent function. In particular, we exclude the case where $H$ is identically zero.

Comment: 1. If I understand correctly, the set of integrals of motion or the first integrals is a subset of the constants of motion which depend only on the phase space variables $(q,p)$ and does not depend on time explicitly. 2. They are constants whether or not equations of motions are satisfied. Is this correct?

Comment: @mithusengupta123: Thanks for the feedback.  1. Correct. 2. Incorrect. They are not necessarily constant if the EOMs are not satisfied.

Comment: Can you write their difference in simple English? I couldn't follow the mathematical definition very well. Thanks in advance.