# How to prove that a Hamiltonian system is *not* Liouville integrable?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

To show that a system is [Liouville integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability), we just need to find $n$ independent functions $f_j$ such that 
$\{ f_i, f_j \} = 0$.

But how to prove that such a set of functions do not exist? For example, how to do this for the three-body problem?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56016/226902

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Explicitly proving non-integrability of an *arbitrary* Hamiltonian system is an open problem.

For some classes of Hamiltonian systems (e.g systems on a plane) is possible to prove **explicitly** the *non-integrability* of the system, using theorems of Poincare, Burns, Ziglin and Yoshida (and generalizations).

For example there is a theorem of Poincare:

> For a hamiltonian of the form:
>
> 1:    $ H = \frac{p_x^2 + p_y^2}{2} + V(x,y)$
>
> If the hamiltonian (1) can have an *isolated periodic solution*, then
>   the system is **not integrable** (specificaly there **does not exist** a second integral of motion that is independent of the $H$)

For the meaning of *isolated periodic solution* in relation to Poincare's method see for example [here](http://www.ics.org.ru/doc?pdf=1046&%3Bdir=e&origin=publication_detail) and [here](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/chenciner.pdf)

The theorem of Ziglin has more extensive applications:

> If the Hamiltonian system (1) is integrable, and there is a [*monodromy
>   matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_matrix) $\Delta$ from the [monodromy group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy) of the *vertical variations
>   equation*, then any other *monodromy matrix* $\Delta'$ must commute
>   with $\Delta$ or its eigenvalues must be $i, -i$

Yoshida's theorem involves hamiltonian systems with homogeneopus potentials (for example see [here](http://www2.caminos.upm.es/Departamentos/matematicas/morales%20ruiz/homfin.pdf) for a generalisation)

Related approaches involve the [Painleve properties and characterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painlev%C3%A9_transcendents) of the equations of motion (e.g [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2007/073/sigma07-073.pdf), [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/Kruskal_Birthday.pdf) and [here](http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/pub/Rapports/2600-2699/2681.pdf)).

Furthermore there are approaches to integrability which involve [Differential Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) (i.e [Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) for differential equations) where one has the analogy *solvability* -> *integrability*. This approach can also unify various other approaches (e.g [here](http://www2.caminos.upm.es/Departamentos/matematicas/morales%20ruiz/obsfin.pdf) and [here](http://www-ma2.upc.edu/juan/Manga1.pdf))

Comment: 29.03.18: Several links are now dead.

Answer (score 5):

User Nikos M has already given a good answer. Here we would like to mention the following Poincare theorem, which can be used to prove non-existence of integrals of motion, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205868/2451) Phys.SE post.

> *Poincare theorem (1892):*
>
> - Consider an autonomous Hamiltonian system in a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold $({\cal M}, \{\cdot,\cdot\})$ equipped with Hamiltonian function $H:{\cal M}\to \mathbb{R}$.
> - Let there be given with a periodic solution $\Gamma(t)=\Gamma(t+T)$ with start & end point $p=\Gamma(0)=\Gamma(T)\in {\cal M}$.
> - Let there be given $r$ functionally independent, Poisson-commuting integrals of motion $F_1,\ldots, F_r$ in a tubular neighborhood ${\cal U}\subseteq {\cal M}$ of $\Gamma$, where $r\leq n$, and where the Hamiltonian $H|_{\cal U}$ is a function of $F_1,\ldots, F_r$ only.
> - Let $\sigma: {\cal M} \times \mathbb{R} \to {\cal M}$ denote the Hamiltonian [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)) corresponding to the Hamiltonian vector field $X_{-H}=\{-H,\cdot\}$.
>
> Then the [monodromy map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_matrix)
> $\sigma_{\ast}(p,T): T_p{\cal M}\to T_p{\cal M}$ at the point $p$ has $r$ eigenvectors $X_{-F_1}(p), \ldots, X_{-F_r}(p),$ and $r$ co-eigenvectors $\mathrm{d}F_1(p), \ldots, \mathrm{d}F_r(p),$ all with eigenvalue $1$.
> In fact, the monodromy map $\sigma_{\ast}(p,T)$ has ([generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector)) eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity $2r$.

*Sketched proof of Poincare theorem:*

1. In a neighborhood of $p\in {\cal M}$, we can use the [Caratheodory–Jacobi–Lie theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Lie_theorem) to construct local [Darboux coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem)
   $$ z^I ~=~(\varphi^1, \ldots, \varphi^r, q^1,\ldots, q^{n-r}, p_1,\ldots, p_{n-r}, F_1, \ldots, F_r ), $$
   with non-zero canonical Poisson brackets
   $$ \{\varphi^i, F_j\} ~=~\delta^i_j, \qquad i,j\in\{1, \ldots, r\},$$
   $$ \{q^a, p_b\} ~=~\delta^a_b, \qquad a,b\in\{1, \ldots, n-r\}. $$
2. The monodromy matrix
   $$ M^I{}_J ~=~ \frac{\partial z^I(T)}{\partial z^J(0)}, \qquad I,J\in\{1, \ldots, 2n\}, $$
   at the point $p$ has $r$ co-eigenvectors
   $$\begin{align}
   &\begin{bmatrix} \vec{0}^T{}_{1\times r}& \vec{0}^T{}_{1\times 2(n-r)}&\vec{e}_i^T{}_{1\times r}\end{bmatrix}_{1\times 2n}\cr
   ~=~& \frac{\partial F_i(z(0))}{\partial z^I(0)}\cr
   ~=~&\frac{\partial F_i(z(T))}{\partial z^I(0)} \cr
   ~=~&\frac{\partial F_i(z(T))}{\partial z^J(T)}\frac{\partial z^J(T)}{\partial z^I(0)}\cr
   ~=~&\frac{\partial F_i(z(0))}{\partial z^J(0)} M^J{}_I,\end{align} $$
   $i\in\{1, \ldots, r\}$, with eigenvalue 1.
3. Since the flow $\sigma$ is Hamiltonian, the monodromy matrix $M$ must be [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix)
   $$\begin{align} \{z^I(T),z^J(T)\}~=~& \{z^I(0),z^J(0)\}, \cr 
   I,J~\in~&\{1, \ldots, 2n\},\end{align} $$
   or equivalently,
   $$\begin{align} M^T\omega M~=~&\omega, \cr 
   \omega ~=~& \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{0}_{n\times n} &  -\mathbb{1}_{n\times n}\cr \mathbb{1}_{n\times n} &  \mathbb{0}_{n\times n}
   \end{bmatrix}_{2n\times 2n} .\end{align}$$
   Therefore the monodromy matrix has $r$ eigenvectors
   $$\begin{align}
   \begin{bmatrix} \vec{e}_i{~}_{r\times 1} \cr \vec{0}{~}_{2(n-r)\times 1} \cr \vec{0}{~}_{r\times 1}\end{bmatrix}_{2n\times 1} 
   ~=~&X^I_{-F_i}\cr
   ~=~&\{z^I(0),F_i \}\cr 
   ~=~&\{z^I(T),F_i \} \cr 
   ~=~&\frac{\partial z^I(T)}{\partial z^J(0)} \{z^J(0),F_i \}\cr
   ~=~& M^I{}_J \{z^J(0),F_i \}\cr
   ~=~& M^I{}_J X^J_{-F_i},\end{align}$$
   $i\in\{1, \ldots, r\}$, with eigenvalue 1.
4. Altogether, we deduce that the monodromy matrix $M$ has the following block-triangular form
   $$ M ~=~ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{1}_{r\times r} & \ast & \ast \cr 
   \mathbb{0}_{2(n-r)\times r} & \ast & \ast \cr
   \mathbb{0}_{r\times r} &\mathbb{0}_{r\times 2(n-r)}& \mathbb{1}_{r\times r}\end{bmatrix}_{2n\times 2n} .$$
   Hence the characteristic polynomial $\det(M-\lambda \mathbb{1}_{2n\times 2n} )$ has generalized eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity $2r$. $\Box$

> *Poincare corollary:* If an autonomous Hamiltonian [Liouville-integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) system has a periodic solution $\Gamma(t)=\Gamma(t+T)$, then the [monodromy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_matrix) for the linearized system along $\Gamma$ can only have 1 as a ([generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector)) eigenvalue.

References:

1. H. Poincare, [*Les Methodes Nouvelles de la Mecanique Celeste*](https://archive.org/stream/lesmthodesnouv001poin#page/198/mode/2up), Vol. I, (1892); p. 192-198.
2. A. Chenciner, [*Poincare and the Three-Body Problem*](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/chenciner.pdf), (2012); p. 87. (Hat tip: [Nikos M.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/44176/nikos-m))
3. J.J. Morales-Ruiz, *Differential Galois Theory and Non-Integrability of Hamiltonian Systems,* [Progress in Math. 179 (1999)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8718-2); p. 3-4 & p. 57.