# Analytic proof of the non-integrability of the Henon-Heiles system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

The [Henon-Heiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non-Heiles_System) potential is

$$ U(x,y ) = \frac{1}{2} (x^2 + y^2 + 2 x^2 y - \frac{2}{3} y^3) .$$

This is a two degree-of-freedom system. The full Hamiltonian is

$$ H = p_x^2 + p_y^2 + U(x,y )  . $$

It is shown by numerics that it is non-integrable. But can one prove it rigorously analytically? The problem boils down to proving the non-existence of a second first-integral/integral-of-motion.

If this problem is too difficult, is there any simpler model whose non-integrability can be proven analytically?

Answer (score 9):

General analytic methods to prove non-integrability are discussed in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126992/2451) Phys.SE post. In this answer, we will sketch how to apply the following Poincare corollary.

> *Poincare corollary:* If an autonomous Hamiltonian [Liouville-integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) system has a periodic solution $z_0(t)=z_0(t+T)$, then the [monodromy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_matrix) for the linearized system along $z_0$ can only have 1 as a ([generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector)) eigenvalue.

A proof of the Poincare corollary is given in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/401055/2451).

[image]

$\uparrow$ Fig. 1. [Poincare maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) in the $(y,\dot{y})$ plane with $(x,\dot{x})=(0,0)$ for various fixed energy-levels $E$ of the [Henon-Heiles (HH) system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non%E2%80%93Heiles_system). We consider below the outermost periodic orbit for $E=1/6$ and $E=1/12$.

*Sketched analytic proof that the HH system is not integrable:* The [HH system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Henon-HeilesEquation.html) has Lagrangian$^1$
$$\begin{align} L ~=~&T-V, \cr 
T ~=~&\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)
~=~\frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2), \cr
V~=~&\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)+x^2y-\frac{1}{3}y^3
~=~\frac{r^2}{2}+\frac{r^3}{3}\sin 3\theta, \cr 
x+iy ~\equiv~& re^{i\theta}. \end{align}\tag{1}$$
The [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are
$$ -\ddot{x}_0~=~x_0 +2x_0y_0, \tag{2}$$
$$ -\ddot{y}_0~=~y_0 +x_0^2-y_0^2.\tag{3} $$
We seek a periodic solution $y_0(t)=y_0(t+T)$ with $x_0(t)\equiv 0$. Then eq. (2) is automatically satisfied. The energy
$$ E~=~ \frac{1}{2}\dot{y}_0^2+\frac{1}{2}y_0^2 -\frac{1}{3}y_0^3 \tag{4}$$
is conserved. Consider $(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)+ (\xi,\eta)$, where $(\xi,\eta)$ is an infinitesimal fluctuation. The linearized EL equations
$$ \ddot{\xi}~=~-(1+2y_0)\xi ,\tag{5} $$
$$\ddot{\eta}~=~(2y_0-1)\eta,\tag{6}$$
decouple. [The eq. (6) corresponds to dimensional reduction to the 1D subsystem in the $y$-direction alone. This is manifestly integrable, so we already know that the corresponding 2 generalized eigenvalues for the monodromy matrix in the $y$-direction is $1$. Hence eq. (5) will be the actual integrability test.]

*First attempt: $E=\frac{1}{6}$.* The first integral (4) becomes
$$\dot{y}_0~=~\pm (1-y_0)\sqrt{y_0+1/2}, \qquad -\frac{1}{2}~\leq~y_0~\leq~1. \tag{7}$$
It has solution
$$ y_0(t)~=~ \frac{3}{2}\tanh u-\frac{1}{2} 
~=~1-\frac{3/2}{\cosh^2u},\qquad u~\equiv~\frac{t}{2}.\tag{8} $$
Unfortunately the period is infinite $T=\infty$.
For the record, the linearized eqs. (5) & (6) become [Legendre's DE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html)
$$ \frac{d^2\xi}{du^2}~=~- 12\xi \tanh^2 u ,   \tag{9}$$
$$ \frac{d^2\eta}{du^2}~=~\left(4 - \frac{12}{\cosh^2 u}\right) \eta.   \tag{10}$$

*Second attempt: $E=\frac{1}{12}$.* The first integral (4) becomes
$$\begin{align}\dot{y}_0~=~&\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}(y_0-1)(y_0^2-y_0-1/2)}, \cr 
\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}~\leq~&y_0~\leq~\frac{1}{2}.\end{align}\tag{11}$$
It has a solution in terms of [Jacobi elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions)
$$\begin{align} y_0(t)~=~& \sqrt{3}{\rm sn}^2u +\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}, \cr 
{\rm sn} u~\equiv~&{\rm sn}(u|m\!=\!2), \cr 
u~\equiv~&\frac{t}{2\sqrt[4]{3}}.\end{align}\tag{12} $$
The linearized eqs. (5) & (6) become [Lamé's DE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LamesDifferentialEquation.html) on Jacobi form$^2$
$$ \frac{d^2\xi}{du^2}~=~\left(12-8\sqrt{3}- 24 {\rm sn}^2u \right) \xi   \tag{13},$$
$$ \frac{d^2\eta}{du^2}~=~\left(24 {\rm sn}^2u - 12\right) \eta   \tag{14}.$$
Eqs. (13) & (14) may in principle be solved analytically. At this stage we admittedly just plugged eq. (13) into Mathematica, and checked numerically that the corresponding 2 generalized eigenvalues for the monodromy matrix in the $x$-direction are far from 1. Hence the HH system is not integrable, cf. the Poincare corollary.  $\Box$

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* 3rd edition, Section 11.6.

--

$^1$ Although the $4\times 4$ monodromy matrix refers to the 4D phase space, it is convenient to perform most of analysis in the 2D configuration space, and postpone the Legendre transformation.

$^2$ One solution to eq. (14) is
$$\eta_1(u)~:=~{\rm sn}u~{\rm cn}u~{\rm dn}u. \tag{15}$$
Another independent solution can in principle be found from the formula
$$ \eta_2(u)~:=~\eta_1(u)\int^u\! \frac{du^{\prime}}{\eta_1(u^{\prime})^2}. \tag{16}$$

Comment: Presumably the same strategy would hold to show that the 3-particle Toda system - which can be reduced to 2 positions and 2 momenta and is closely related to HH -  *is* integrable?   (Of course we know it is as a second invariant of motion is known).