# Simplest model of chaos with time-independent smooth Hamiltonian and trivial topology?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory

**What is the simplest model of chaos governed by a time-independent smooth Hamiltonian on a phase-space with trivial topology?**

We know that...

- With trivial topology, the [minimal number of dimension to exhibit chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#Minimum_complexity_of_a_chaotic_system) with first-order ODEs is three (e.g., the [Lorentz system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system)), but these are of course not Hamiltonian.
- Indeed, time-independent Hamiltonian systems of two phase-space dimensions (one configuration variable) cannot be chaotic because the trajectories follow the fixed-energy surfaces which [foiliate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation) the phase space.  Thus we need four phase-space dimensions (two configuration variables).
- There exist time-*dependent* examples of Hamiltonian chaos in two-dimensional phase space, e.g., the [kicked-top](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kicked_top).
- There exist discrete-time non-smooth chaotic maps in two-dimensions that preserve area, e.g., [Baker's map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_map).
- [Hadamard's billiards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_dynamical_system) is a time-independent chaotic Hamiltonian system on a four-dimensional phase space.  However, it has *non*-trivial topology (a two-holed donut), exhibiting chaos on account of constant negative curvature.

The [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) with equal masses and equal arm lengths has Hamiltonian

$$H(\theta_1,p_1,\theta_2,p_2)= \frac{1}{6} m l^2 \left ( {\dot \theta_2}^2 + 4 {\dot \theta_1}^2 + 3 {\dot \theta_1} {\dot \theta_2} \cos (\theta_1-\theta_2) \right ) - \frac{1}{2} m g l \left ( 3 \cos \theta_1 + \cos \theta_2 \right ).$$

where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the angles of the top and bottom arm with respect to the vertical direction, and $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the respective conjugate momenta.  **This satisfies all our specific requirements except that it is not very simple.**

(Note that I am merely extending [this question on /r/physics](https://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/comments/61gd73/simplest_chaotic_hamiltonian_system/), which lacked the specialization to topologically trivial phase spaces.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A 1D autonomous system is always Liouville integrable – the Hamiltonian $H$ itself is an integral of motion – so we would have to consider at least 2D to find chaos.
2. A quadratic potential $V$ yields a linear system, which doesn't exhibit chaos. So the potential $V$ should contain cubic or higher terms.
3. The potential should mix coordinates (e.g., terms like $x_2^2x_1 $) so that the system isn't separable into two 1D systems.
4. The [Henon-Heiles system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non%E2%80%93Heiles_system) in 2D with a potential $V$ containing both quadratic and cubic terms is often given as the standard example of chaos. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205868/2451) Phys.SE post.
5. The homogeneous Henon-Heiles system with a purely cubic potential $V$ is an even simpler system: the Hamiltonian
   $$H(x_1,p_1,x_2,p_2) = \frac{g}{3}x_1^3 + x_1 x_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(p_1^2 + p_2^2\right)$$
   is non-integrable for many value of $g$, including $g \in (-\infty,1)$.
   See Example 3 (Eq. 5.2) in Section 5.1 of Ref. 1.

References:

1. J.J. Morales-Ruiz, *Differential Galois Theory and Non-Integrability of Hamiltonian Systems,* [Progress in Math. 179 (1999)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8718-2). [[free PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.720.1799&rep=rep1&type=pdf)].

Comment: This is darn close to being an objective answer to "simplest", a seemingly subjective criterion.  Just what I was hoping for.  Stupendous!  Thanks Qmechanic for showing there's still a bit of magic on Physics.SE.

Comment: Indeed, pretty good answer! Note that, besides the [citeseerx link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.720.1799&rep=rep1&type=pdf) provided by @JessRiedel 's edit, a pdf file of Ref. 1 is also available in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Juan_Morales-Ruiz/publication/245916648_Differential_Galois_Theory_and_Non-Integrability_of_Hamiltonian_Systems/links/54f5f3220cf21d8b8a5bce1c/Differential-Galois-Theory-and-Non-Integrability-of-Hamiltonian-Systems.pdf).

Comment: Solutions tend to explode to infinity.  Any examples that don't?