# Does $\{\rho(q,p),H(q,p)\}=0$ necessarily imply $\rho(q,p)=\rho(H)$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, equilibrium, phase-space

In classical statistical mechanics, the [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29#Poisson_bracket) tells that for a system in equilibrium the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket#Definition_in_canonical_coordinates) $$\{\rho(q,p),H(q,p)\}=0.\tag{1}$$

**1**. Does it *necessarily* imply $\rho(q,p)=\rho(H(q,p))$? In other words, I'm not asking whether $\rho(H(q,p))$ satisfies (1). It of course does. But is it not possible to have other functional forms $\rho(q,p)$ which are nor necessarily of the form $\rho(H(q,p))$ but still satisfying (1)?

**2**. In the answer to question **1** is in negative, is it possible to mathematically derive or restrict the possible functional forms of $\rho(H)$? If not mathematically, can we rule out physically some functional forms of $\rho(H)$ (if not all)? After all, apparently any function $\rho(H(q,p))$ will satisfy (1).

A coherent, simplistic answer addressing all the questions above will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1 - no. Consider $H = \frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m} + V(|\mathbf{r}|)$. Note how $\{\mathbf{L}^2,H\} = 0$, thus any sufficiently smooth function $f(\mathbf{L}^2,H)$ will also have a zero Poisson bracket with $H$. This generalizes in a straightforward fashion to all conserved quantities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (1) implies $\rho$ is a constant of motion, and nothing more or less. Since a system of phase space dimension $2N$ can have up to $2N$ functionally independent constants of motion (and in fact locally always has this maximal number of such constants, cf. e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56016/50583)), $\rho$ need not be functionally dependent on $H$.
2. Not only does every function $\rho(H(q,p))$ satisfy (1), *every constant of motion* satisfies (1), so, at least locally, the most general solution of (1) is a function of $H$ and $2N-1$ functionally indepedent constants of motion $I_1(q,p),\dots, I_{2N-1}(q,p)$. Note that this does not actually tell you anything new because it was a function of the $2N$ functionally independent $q,p$ to begin with! Since you have made no restrictions about what sort of physical system we are considering, it seems impossible to restrict the form of $\rho$ in any way.