# Liouville's theorem and uniform probability density

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, equilibrium, phase-space, poisson-brackets

In Kardar's book on statistical physics it is claimed that [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) gives support for the common assumption that the points in phase space compatible with the hamiltonian are all equally probable. As far as I can gather the reasoning goes as follows: in equilibrium $$\partial \rho/\partial t = -\{\rho, H\}=0$$ and this is compatible with the assumption that $\rho$ is purely a function of $H$ since this yields $$\{\rho, H\}=\rho'(H)\{H, H\}=0.$$ My questions are:

1. Are all functions $\rho$ that satisfy $\{\rho, H\}=0$ *necessarily* of the form $\rho(H)$?
2. If not, the PDFs of the form $\rho = \rho(H)$ are only a subset of the (possibly much larger) set of possible PDFs that satisfy $\{\rho, H\}=0$ and we seem to be no better off than we were before invoking Liouville's theorem.

   Are there additional facts/assumptions that together with the requirement $\{\rho, H\}=0$ make $\rho = \rho(H)$ a well founded assumption?

Comment: Near [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341561/does-rhoq-p-hq-p-0-necessarily-imply-rhoq-p-rhoh?rq=1). In a multidimensional phase space invariant hypersurfaces  are  different, in general. Behold a superintegrable system!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer your question I would like to make this comment about the Liouville equation: it is a *necessary* condition on $\rho$, but it is *not sufficient*. This means that the correct $\rho$ must satisfy the Liouville equation, but not every $\rho$ that satisfies the Liouville equation is the correct probability density of microstate.

Turning to your first question, the answer is, no, $\rho(H)$ is not the only form that satisfies the Liouville equation. But the fact that $\rho(H)$ *is* an acceptable solution is important because it ties $\rho$ to a mechanical observable, the energy of the system. The premise of thermodynamics is that the macroscopic state is defined by a small number of variables, $(E,V,N)$, for example. A theory that would give $\rho=\rho(\Gamma)$ as a function of the microstate $\Gamma$ is of no use if $\Gamma$ is not something that we can observe and control experimentally.

Gibbs noticed that $\rho(H)$ is an acceptable solution and set out to guess mathematical forms of $\rho(H)$ that made thermodynamic  sense. His first guess was the canonical distribution $\rho = c e^{-H/\Theta}$. Gibbs explained his reasons for choosing the exponential form as [follows](https://archive.org/details/elementaryprinci00gibbrich/page/32/mode/2up) (Gibbs uses $P$ for what we have called $\rho$):

> The distribution represented by
> \begin{equation}\tag{90}
>    \eta=\log P = \frac{\psi-\epsilon}{\Theta},
> \end{equation}
> or
> \begin{equation}\tag{91}
>    P = e^{\dfrac{\psi-\epsilon}{\Theta}},
> \end{equation}
> where $\Theta$ and $\psi$ are constants, and $\Theta$ positive, seems to represent the most simple case conceivable, since it has the property
> that when the system consists of parts with separate energies,
> the laws of the distribution in phase of the separate parts are
> of the same nature, a property which enormously simplifies
> the discussion, and is the foundation of extremely important
> relations to thermodynamics.

*"Seems to represent the most simple case conceivable"* is a modest way of saying "a stroke of genius"!